# Linq Join, group by multiple field

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core-3.1, ef-core-3.1

I have two tables as follows

```
public class Customer
{
    public string Id{ get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Currency), Column(TypeName = "decimal(18,2)")]
    public decimal Balance { get; set; }

    [Display(Name ="Time Registered")]
    public DateTime TimeRegistered { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("Beneficiary")]
    public ICollection<WalletTransaction> TransactionsReceived { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("Sender")]
    public ICollection<WalletTransaction> TransactionsInitiated { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public class WalletTransaction
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public TransactionType TrasactionType { get; set; }

    public decimal Amount { get; set; }

    public string SenderId { get; set; }

    public string ReceipientId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("SenderId")]
    public Customer Sender { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ReceipientId")]
    public Customer Beneficiary { get; set; }
}
```

and transaction types can be in the following enum

```
public enum TransactionType
{
    Deposit=1,Transfer=2,Withdrawal=3
}
```

Now I need to get summaries of each customer's transaction broken down into the different transaction types as follows:

```
Name of CustomerA
    Deposit=Sum of the amount value in all his transactions of transaction type Deposit
    Transfer=Sum of the amount value in all his transactions of transaction type Transfer
    Withdrawal=Sum of the amount value in all his transactions of transaction type Withdrawal
Name of CustomerB
    Deposit=Sum of the amount value in all his transactions of transaction type Deposit
    Transfer=Sum of the amount value in all his transactions of transaction type Transfer
    Withdrawal=Sum of the amount value in all his transactions of transaction type Withdrawal
Name of CustomerC
    Deposit=Sum of the amount value in all his transactions of transaction type Deposit
    Transfer=Sum of the amount value in all his transactions of transaction type Transfer
    Withdrawal=Sum of the amount value in all his transactions of transaction type Withdrawal
etc.
```

I am lost as how to achieve that
My thought is that I need to create the linq query to join the customer table and the transactions table to get the name of the customer from the customers table. Thenafter, group the transactions by the customer and also by the transaction type. I am not sure whether or not that is correct but even if it is, I dont know how to go about it.

I have tried to do this

```
var customerTransactions = await _context.Customers
            .Include(c => c.TransactionsInitiated)
            .Select(a => new
            {
                //Looking for how to break down he transactions by the transaction types here
            })
            .OrderByDescending(s=>s.TotalAmount)//Not sure too how to order the result
            .ToListAsync();
```

Please guide me on how to resolve these.
Thank you

Comment: @GertArnold, By all transactions, I mean all TransactionsInitated by the Customer. Customers have accounts. Funds can be transferred to a customer's account by another customer. That is not the type of transaction I am trying to get. I am trying to get the ones initiated by the customer as either Deposit into his account, transfer to another account or withdrawal

Comment: Yes. I know that the navigation property has taken care of join but how can I go about getting the sum of the ammounts and do the filtering by TransactionType ?

Comment: I am still not able to make out exactly how you said it should be done. Could you please make the answer more elaborate or if possible create an answer and show how the query so I can accept and it can also help others

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have navigation properties you don't need `Join` in LINQ statements. Basically what you want can be done in a query like

```cs
_context.Customers
.Select(a => new
{
    c.Name,
    Deposit = c.TransactionsInitiated
        .Where(t => t.TransactionType == TransactionType.Deposit).Sum(t => t.Amount),
    Transfer = c.TransactionsInitiated
        .Where(t => t.TransactionType == TransactionType.Transfer).Sum(t => t.Amount),
    Withdrawal = c.TransactionsInitiated
        .Where(t => t.TransactionType == TransactionType.Withdrawal).Sum(t => t.Amount),
    TotalAmount = c.TransactionsInitiated
        .Sum(t => t.Amount),
})
.OrderByDescending(s => s.TotalAmount)
```

...and EF will join in the generated SQL statement.

Disclaimer: EF core 3 is pretty limited in translating more complex queries into SQL, I'm not sure if this will actually work and I don't have a similar test case handy.

Comment: I've checked your query with EF Core 3.1 and it works.